# Why doesn't triggerRelease have a note parameter in Tone.js?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-midi, tone.js

I'm playing notes from my midi controller using web midi. I'd like a way to hear them so I'm using Tone.js.

I saw it had two methods for playing in realtime:
https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Instruments

```
//trigger the start of a note at `time` with a velocity of 50%
synth.triggerAttack("C4", time, 0.5);

//trigger the release at `time`
synth.triggerRelease(time);
```

But aren't they forgetting the note parameter in triggerRelease? how would it know what note to release?

Also I saw there's a triggerAttackAndRelease but that doesn't help me when I'm playing from a midi controller because I don't know when the release will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `triggerRelease` method does take a note as an argument:

```
soundtrack.synth.triggerRelease(note.renderAbc());
```

It can also take a time to release it at a given time:

```
soundtrack.synth.triggerRelease(note.renderAbc(), releaseTime);
```

The release time is an absolute time on the transport.